# Duda: Multi Task CloudRun Job

Tags: cloud, gcloud

Tengo la siguiente duda para los que han trabajado con los servicios de GCP, especificamente **CloudRun Job**.

**Caso**

Tengo un directorio con 6 shell en bash el cual un script con otro tiene una "dependencia", el cual explicaré, script 1 debe terminar para seguir con script 2 ( y el mismo caso para el script 3,4 y 5,6). Actualmente tengo un septimo script el cual ejecuta en orden lo que yo quiero, pero aprovechando la ventaja del multi task del Job de CloudRun necesito que se ejecuten 3 Task en simultanéo ejecutando el script 1 y el 2, finalizando el primer task, segundo task que ejecute el script 3 y 4, y el 3r task que ejecute el script 5 y 6. Todo esto corriendo los 3 task al mismo tiempo, he leido documentación respecto pero está enfocado a otros lenguajes y no hay simil con bash.

¿Que camino podría tomar?

dejo algunas evidencias de como lo estoy armando:

Docker que contiene mis 6 scripts dentro del directorio Shell

```
FROM CUSTOM/IMAGE:TAG
COPY shell/ /shell/

RUN chown -R cloudsdk:root /shell/ \
    && chmod +x /shell/*

ENV PORT 8080
EXPOSE 8080
HEALTHCHECK CMD curl --fail http://localhost/healthcheck:$PORT || exit 1

WORKDIR /shell
USER cloudsdk

CMD ["/bin/bash", "-c"]
```

[Configuración del job de CloudRun (imagen), es donde le configuro los argumentos para ejecutar los script pero no logro dar con la ejecución multitask](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bhh6N.png)

1. He probado agregarle al container argumentos de ejecución, ya que el contenedor mediante CMD es bash, solo le he pasado los nombre de los script para que los ejecute sin llegar al multitask.
2. He activado el paralelismo en donde ejecuta todo (los 6 scripts) en 2 task distintos
3. Traté de levantar un YAML con dependencias el cual veia factible, pero por compatiblidad no pudo ser aplicado

Comment: Please note that this is the English-only version of StackOverflow. You can find the Spanish version at https://es.stackoverflow.com/ .